# Collision detection between imageview and drawables

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-drawable, imagebutton

I'm trying to collide my ball1 to greengreen drawable. how can I determine the collision?

```js
  public boolean CheckCollisionred(View ballr,View rr_1,View rg_3) {
    Rect R1 = new Rect(ballr.getLeft(), ballr.getTop(), ballr.getRight(), ballr.getBottom());
    Rect R2 = new Rect(rr_1.getLeft(), rr_1.getTop(), rr_1.getRight(), rr_1.getBottom());
    Rect R3 = new Rect(rg_3.getLeft(), rg_3.getTop(), rg_3.getRight(), rg_3.getBottom());
    return R1.setIntersect(R2, R3);
 
}

@Override
public void run() {startballanimation();
    if (CheckCollisionred()) {
        Score++;
    }else
        Score--;
}
```

UPDATE: this is showing me error "Checkcollisionred() in main activity cannot be applied to expected parameters, Actual arguments"

edit: the problem is I have an image button that displays the drawables that I want to collide .

Comment: Use the answers to the linked question to find the location of the Drawables then use some `if` statements to detect collisions.

Comment: You should learn about libraries which are intended for games like this. LibGDX is a very popular one.

Comment: Please explain in more detail about what you want your app to do and what it is currently doing. Do the drawables move? Do you want them to? Feel free to post some screenshots if that will help.

Comment: so there are three image buttons in place  at the bottom of the screen and there are balls going down from the top. the drawables are not moving.when the designated drawable for the ball gets tapped,the score will add...so basically the drawable will catch the balls.. @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Okay, let's simplify this. It sounds like the falling balls have nothing to do with your current question. Rather, you want to move some object on the screen as the user taps or drags on the screen. Is that correct? If so, create a [mcve] which attempts to do this. This code example should not have any balls, just the object that you are trying to move.

Comment: If I misunderstand your question, the same advice applies: break it down to smaller, simpler pieces. Pick one piece and figure out how to do it. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: if(the ball collides with the  drawables){ score++}else show game over  that's basically it @Code-Apprentice

Comment: i'll keep that noted

Comment: "if(the ball collides with the drawables){ score++}" Is not valid Java. You seem to have several questions. From the original question, you are asking how to do "the ball collides with the drawables". This leads back to my original comment: First get the location and size of a ball and of each drawable. Then determine if they collide.

Comment: I suggest you simplify this to a single ball and a single drawable.

Comment: that's just an example for you to understand. you said that I should get the "location and size of the ball" I clearly don't know how to do that.that's why i'm asking. alright I simplify.

Comment: The ball is an `ImageView`. Read the link in my very first post to find how to get the location and size of any `View`.

Comment: thanks,it's a bit clear now I should use view.getLocationOnScreen for the ball how about for the drawable? and how can I determine if they collide? should I use .intersects?

Comment: Which one? You have 16 of them in your code. It will help tremendously if you follow the instructions in my previous comment: create a [mcve]. (Hint: click on this link and read it.)

Comment: You are not refering the objects as parameter to the method, you declared 3 and called with 0

Comment: I don't get it.. can u elaborate? @MarcosVasconcelos

Comment: If you have this: (View ballr,View rr_1,View rg_3) you cant call as () you need tree parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check This  for Finding Collision of Two Views.
You can add that drawable in any Imageview.

```
public boolean CheckCollision(View v1,View v2) {
    Rect R1=new Rect(v1.getLeft(), v1.getTop(), v1.getRight(), v1.getBottom());
    Rect R2=new Rect(v2.getLeft(), v2.getTop(), v2.getRight(), v2.getBottom());
    return R1.intersect(R2);
}
```

You can Add drawable as src

```
    <ImageView
android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
```

Comment: in src property.

Comment: how can I set the drawable in image view? this one is giving me an error gr1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.greengreen);

Comment: can you elaborate? please thanks

Comment: you should use findViewById(R.id.imgLogo)

Comment: what if I want the ball1 to collide in many drawables? can I use  public boolean CheckCollision(View v1,View v2,v3,v4) {
    Rect R1=new Rect(v1.getLeft(), v1.getTop(), v1.getRight(), v1.getBottom());
    Rect R2=new Rect(v2.getLeft(), v2.getTop(), v2.getRight(), v2.getBottom());
    return R1.intersect(R2);
}

Comment: You can do it by this

 public boolean CheckCollision(View v1,View v2,View v3) {
        Rect R1=new Rect(v1.getLeft(), v1.getTop(), v1.getRight(), v1.getBottom());
        Rect R2=new Rect(v2.getLeft(), v2.getTop(), v2.getRight(), v2.getBottom());
        Rect R3=new Rect(v3.getLeft(), v3.getTop(), v3.getRight(), v3.getBottom());
        return R1.setIntersect(R2,R3);
    }

Comment: will I place the id in view? example: View my_id

Comment: yeah. I have already added in the answer. You can Check..

Comment: thanks.last question.  can I return many rect?

Comment: public boolean CheckCollisionred(View ball1, View rr,View rg, View ry,View rb) {
        Rect R1=new Rect(ball1.getLeft(), ball1.getTop(), ball1.getRight(), ball1.getBottom());
        Rect R2=new Rect(rr.getLeft(), rr.getTop(), rr.getRight(), rr.getBottom());
        Rect R3=new Rect(rg.getLeft(), rg.getTop(), rg.getRight(), rg.getBottom());
        Rect R4=new Rect(ry.getLeft(), ry.getTop(), ry.getRight(), ry.getBottom());
        Rect R5=new Rect(rb.getLeft(), rb.getTop(), rb.getRight(), rb.getBottom());
        
        return R1.setIntersect(R2,R3);

Comment: I added 4 Views

Comment: anw thanks so much..

Comment: will I use if (Checkcollision()==true) {   statement }else{statement}@Chandan

Comment: if (Checkcollision()) { statement } else{statement}

Comment: I updated the post.. it's showing me error @Chandan